# Powering a stepper motor (on Arduino), what's too much and too little?

Tags: arduino, dc, stepper-motor

I'm an electronics noobie, just learning on an Arduino.
I'm following some tuts online, and bought myself an arduino and a 28byj stepper motor.

It's 5v DC.

I power the arduino via a 9v battery or via USB.
I was warned not to try to run the  motor via the arduino, I have to provide a separate 5v to the motor, I thought if I put 3AA batteries together I get 4.5v or 4 for 6v - but not 5v. :(

So which is better?
A little over or a little under voltage?
If over, how much over can I go, for example can I use a 9v battery?

Thanks in advance! (Feel free to leave any advice, am totally new to this and all suggestions and comments are welcome!)

Comment: If you don't know what you're doing I wouldn't stray more than 30% over the voltage the motor is telling you to use it at. Also, don't use dinky AA batteries, get an AC-DC wall wart that supplies 3A or more. It'll last much longer.

Comment: So, up to 6.5v would be cool?

Comment: Yeah 7V on a 5V motor should be okay

Comment: Thanks! I was scared about burning something out :)

Comment: I don't know how you are hooking things up but it might be wise to connect a fly-back diode to protect the arduino from back emf.

Comment: A little over is better; with 4 double AA batteries I would expect about 8hrs of operation

Answer (score 1):

I would use C or D batteries for initial testing. You may need the increased current capacity to power your motor successfully.

Remember that the GND of the Arduino needs to be connected to the GND of the motor battery pack of four (6 V nominal) C or D cell battery pack.